# AAC Sample Rate and Bit Rate for High Quality Audio?

Tags: audio, mp3, encoding, aac

What are the **AAC Sample Rate** and **Bit Rate** settings to set in order to encode an audio track with a quality comparable to MP3 320kbps?

I need to backup a DVD movie, the default settings for **AAC** are

```
Bitrate (KB/s) 128 
Sample Rate (HZ) 44100
```

should I set

```
Bitrate (KB/s) 320
Sample Rate (HZ) 48000
```

or the default are already good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AAC has different ratios against MP3, so thats good question to ask.
AAC has slightly better quality than MP3 in higher bitrates, and is superior to in lower bitrates.

Sample rate: You should keep sample ratio, as resampling looses some quality and up-sample wouldnt do any good.

Bitrate: If you like to have quality comparable to MP3, choose lower when using AAC. 
For example, for 320kbps MP3 like, I would choose 192 to about 226.
This doesn apply to speech in which AAC has better compression ratio, hence same bitrate would yield higher quality.

For higher quality (not highest) movies generally rippers use 192kbps AAC. That would suit good even movies with lots of music and background sounds and effects. For general use and mediocre DVD films 128kbps would do the thing. Regular person should choose 128kbps, audiophile or movie lover may choose slightly more.

Comment: 192 kbps AAC - for how many chanels ?

Comment: "Slightly"? Technically, the difference between AAC and MP3 is almost as big as the difference between MP3 and MP2. Actually in double blind tests, AAC already sounded indistinguishable to CD for most listeners and most songs at 128 kbit/s, while they could still tell the difference between CD and MP3 at 192 kbit/s. That's a bit more than "slightly". AAC with 96 kbit/s already beats the best FM radio you've ever listened to with ease. AAC is highly underrated as an audio format.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the sample rate the same as the original, but you can get away with reducing the bit rate somewhat, as AAC is more efficient than MP3.

Answer (score 2):

AAC efficiency highly depends on the encoder that's used, of which there are many. Bad AAC encoders can be less efficient than MP3. The number of channels you are encoding is also very important, I assume it's stereo, based on the 128 kbps default.

128 kbps AAC stereo, even with the best encoder, will definitely sound worse than 320 kbps MP3.

Always encode in a sample rate of 44.1 kHz for stereo AAC-LC, encoding in 48 kHz will be less efficient, even if it's the native sample rate.

With a good AAC encoder, 160 kbps can be mostly transparent, but to reach 320 kbps MP3 quality level, 192-224 kbps should be a good range. 256 kbps AAC can definitely be superior to 320 kbps MP3, which is actually not always transparent.